# How do I expand my Windows 8.1 Store App width when SettingsFlyout is displayed?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm in the process of porting my App to Windows 8.1 from 8, and had been using the Callisto Settings Flyout in Wide (646 pixel mode).

Windows 8.1 changed the way the Settings work, and a narrow app can now show it's settings, and therefore may be as narrow as 320pixels, which isn't wide enough to hold a wide flyout.

On Windows 8 you could call TryUnsnap() which would make the window wider, but that's deprecated and now does nothing.  So what options do I have to make my flyout visible.

I had hoped that because it's a top level window that it would span across the window boundary, but that was wishful thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Having looked around for any Microsoft App that has a wide about box, I finally found one in Xbox Live.  It looks as though they're resizing the flyout to the width of the window at the time it's opened.

That's probably a reasonable solution, as long as your flyout has fluid layout.

Comment: This is indeed the solution. To rephrase: show a wide flyout when you can, and a narrow flyout when you must.